# Example of sequence with no dominating function but is uniformly integrable so limit holds

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a sequence of functions on
    $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow
0$, the hypothesis of the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem
    does not hold, but the sequence is uniformly integrable both
    locally and at infinity, and so
    $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,\infty)} f_n(x)\,dx = 0$

Been trying to think of one for a week and a half... can't come up with anything... Would appreciate help on this one!! Also details on why it works is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f_n=\frac  1 n I_{(n,n+1)}$. If $f_n \leq g$ for alll $n$ then  $\int g=\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for posting this twice. It was unintentional.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it! How would I show that this function is uniformly integrabe both locally and at infinity?

Comment: $\int_{\{x:f_n(x)>2\}} f_n=0$ for all  $n $. Hence $(f_n)$ uniformly integrable. @MathematicalMushroom